# Make eclipse understand BOOST_AUTO

Tags: c++, eclipse, syntax-error

I'm using a lot of `BOOST_AUTO`, most often in `for` loops like this:

```
for(BOOST_AUTO(it, container.begin()); it != container.end(); ++it) {
    // Do something useful
}
```

The code compiles fine, but Eclipse underlines it in yellow and Eclipse claims a syntax error. I have the boost include path in the project's paths. How can I convince Eclipse that the syntax is quite alright?

Edit: I have to use `BOOST_AUTO` because I can't use c++11 due to compatibility issues.

**Update:** It seems that this problem only occurs with Eclipse 4.3.0. I switched to 4.2.2 and the indexer is quite happy with `BOOST_AUTO`. If I had some more time, I'd try to investigate what changed in the indexer between these two versions, but unfortunately, I don't.

Comment: Care to elaborate on the downvote on a 6 weeks old question?

Answer (score 1):

This is rather inevitable when you use complicated macros. See, IDE's and tools are not like compilers, their parsers are not as good. Maybe you should use typedefs as a workaround if the IDE's warnings bother you.

Comment: The warnings don't really bother my, it's more of an annoyance that half of my source file is underlined in yellow and code completion etc no longer work in these sections... And I'm relatively sure it worked some time ago.